# Adding geom_line mean to reordered geom_point plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to produce a point plot that reorders my values and also has a mean line above the values.

I can produce the plot with the mean line, or the reordered values but not both at the same time because I get the error

> "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?".

I believe I am getting the error as some of my data only has one observation but I don't understand why this only becomes an issue with the reorder data.

In the end all I want is to be able to show the means of the two different values groups for each x value.

Here is my sample code

```
library(ggplot2) 
typ <- c("T", "N", "T", "T", "N")
samplenum <- c(7,7,6,8,8)
values <- c(1,2,1,3,2)
df = data.frame(typ, samplenum, values)
d <- ggplot(df, aes(x= reorder(samplenum, values), y= values))
d <- d +  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.15, height=0.05)) 
d <- d + aes(colour = factor(df$typ))
d <- d + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line")
d
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

---

This is what I am going for

[image]

Here is some steps before the completion sample pictures of what I have produced from my larger data set.

With Line but Not Reordered

[image]

Reordered but No Mean Line

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you need to adjust the group aesthetic. When you use `reorder` you will end up with a discrete scale but you want to draw lines that connect across groups, that's why the error.

You can try this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(samplenum, values), y = values, colour = factor(typ))) +
 geom_jitter(width = 0.15, height = 0.05) +
 stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = factor(typ)))
```

[image]

(I altered your data slighly so it contains more observations.)

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(typ = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    samplenum = c(7, 7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 8, 8
    ), values = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("typ", "samplenum", "values"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

The resulting plot with your input data

[image]